# How to redirect to home screen in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Could you please tell me How to redirect to home screen in react if `key is not found in local storage` .
I have a demo app here

https://codesandbox.io/s/00q3588z1v

When I run application with this url “/abc” full url “https://00q3588z1v.codesandbox.io/abc”
It gives me this error
Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null

Because there is no value in that key.I need should redirect to `/` to or redirect to `Test` component

[image]

Comment: same for me, chrome last version

Comment: please check with `/abc`

Comment: it is returning test2ABC

Comment: remove cache  or local storage then use `/abc`

Comment: i got it, you need a special condition, i can write it if you need it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` in the `Test` component will set `a` in `localStorage` to `"abc"`, but the user might not visit this page before he visits `Test2`, so you need to check if `a` is actually set before you use a string method on it.

If you want to redirect to `/`, you can render a `Redirect` component with a `to` prop.

```
render() {
  console.log("Test1 admin");
  const a = localStorage.getItem("a");

  return (
    <div>
      test2
      {a ? a.toUpperCase() : <Redirect to="/" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to redirect to home component

Comment: actually you didn't get my question

Comment: @user944513 I updated the answer to include a redirect, but how is that relevant to the error you are getting?

Comment: one sec I will explain more ..I need to use any life cycle method so that it will check if value present then it render component else it goes to `/`

Comment: on `life cycle method` like `componentWillmount` where I will check if `local storage have value` if yes it render `Test2` component `else` redirect to `test1`

Comment: yes it is correct ..is there any other way using `lifecycle ` method where I will check this condition ??

Comment: like `componentWillmount`.currently `componentWillmount` is deprecated .. any lifecycle method where I do the same thing

Comment: You could use the [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object given to the component through props and redirect programatically, but the solution in my answer is most likely easier.

Comment: yup ..but if I have 100 component .in all component I have same condition  will I use this condition or make higher order component ?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you need set a condition which will return you back to '/' if a value in localStorage 
is empty

```
if (localStorage.getItem("a")) {
     return (
<div>
  test2
  {localStorage.getItem("a").toUpperCase()}
</div>
     )
} else {
    return <Redirect to="/" />
 }
```